# Factory Girl + Rspec gives following error: ActionView::Template::Error: (object id) is not id value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I defined a Course >> Level >> and Step in factory girl.   Step belongs to level and level belongs to course (each of them has a has_many relationship the other way).

Here is the error (I am not even sure where to start):

```
Failure/Error: before { visit course_level_step_path(course.id, level.id, step.id)}
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   0x003fe5daf528a0 is not id value
```

Here is my required route:

```
 course_level_step GET        /courses/:course_id/levels/:level_id/steps/:id(.:format) steps#show
```

Here my rspec:

```
    describe "attempting a step" do
        let(:course) { FactoryGirl.create(:course)}
        let(:level) { FactoryGirl.create(:level)}
        let(:step) { FactoryGirl.create(:step)}
        before { sign_in user}

        describe "taking a course" do
            before { visit course_level_step_path(course.id, level.id, step.id)}  <<< here is the problem

            it "should increment the user step count" do
                expect do
                    click_button "check answer"
                end.to change(user.user_steps, :count).by(1)
            end

            describe "toggling the button" do
                before { click_button "check answer"}
                it {  should have_selector('input', value: 'remove step')}
            end

        end
```

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :user do
        sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"

        factory :admin do
            admin true
        end
      end

      factory :course do
        sequence(:title) { |n| "Ze Finance Course #{n}" }
        sequence(:description) { |n| "Description for course #{n}" }
      end

      factory :level do
        course
        sequence(:title) { |n| "Ze Finance Level #{n}" }
      end

      factory :step do
        level
        sequence(:description) { |n| "Description for course #{n}" }
      end
end
```

Any guidance on the error and how to solve it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your error seems to be coming from the view. Can you post the code for that and the controller too? Also to save you more trouble later: this line `before { visit course_level_step_path(course.id, level.id, step.id)}` creates one step, two levels, and three courses because of the way Factory Girl works. You probably want to re-write two of your let clauses to `let(:step) { FactoryGirl.create(:step, level: level) }` and `let(:level) { FactoryGirl.create(:level, course: course) }`

Comment: Your suggestion with the lets - actually solved the problem without the need to really dig into the view.  I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.   However it uncovered another error within that my controller is having problems, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326597/relationships-controller-for-creating-an-ajax-relationship-nomethoderror-undef

Comment: ha, I'll take that ;-) I've copy pasted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems to be coming from the view. Can you post the code for that and the controller too? Also to save you more trouble later: this line

```
before { visit course_level_step_path(course.id, level.id, step.id) }
```

creates one step, two levels, and three courses because of the way Factory Girl works. You probably want to re-write two of your let clauses to

```
let(:level) { FactoryGirl.create(:level, course: course) }
let(:step) { FactoryGirl.create(:step, level: level) }
```