# Relationships controller for creating an ajax relationship -NoMethodError: undefined method `[model]_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec

I believe I am having problems with the redirect_to in my controller below.  A course has many levels, which has many steps (step belongs to level, and level belongs to course). I am trying to redirect_to the step.

Here is my route for a step:

```
/courses/:course_id/levels/:level_id/steps/:id(.:format)
```

Here is my error in the controller:

```
Failure/Error: click_button "check answer"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `step_url' for #<UserStepsController:0x007ff8ccc478c8>
```

Here is the controller in which the error occurs:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @step = Step.find(params[:user_step][:step_id])
        current_user.attempt_step!(@step)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @step }
          format.js
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @step = UserStep.find(params[:id]).step
        current_user.remove_user_step!(@step)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @step }
          format.js
        end 
    end
end
```

Here is the rspec

```
    describe "attempting a step" do
        let(:course) { FactoryGirl.create(:course)}
        let(:level) { FactoryGirl.create(:level, course: course) }
        let(:step) { FactoryGirl.create(:step, level: level) }
        before { sign_in user}

        describe "taking a course" do
            before { visit course_level_step_path(course.id, level.id, step.id)}

            it "should increment the user step count" do
                expect do
                    click_button "check answer"
                end.to change(user.user_steps, :count).by(1)
            end

            describe "toggling the button" do
                before { click_button "check answer"}
                it {  should have_selector('input', value: 'remove step')}
            end

        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use redirect_to @variable when you have nested resources. The correct way would be for you to say

```
redirect_to course_level_step_url(@step.level.course.id, @step.level.id, @step.id)
```

Because the thing that gets the route from the instance variable 'thinks' you want the path of the lowercased class name plus _url